# Rspec incredibly slow after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, rspec

after installing the newest Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine all the rspec tests for all my rails applications are running very very slow. Also a colleague of mine has the same problem.

Anyone an idea what it could be?
Its really annoying...

Comment: Are you using ruby from ubuntu's package or via rvm?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My specs were taking 4x longer than my coworkers who are running Vagrant on Mac OSX. I found [this post](http://adamthedeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/ubuntu-mysql-slow-rspec-tests.html) which seems to solve the problem. Apparently anyone using ext4 will experience this unless they follow the instructions on the blog post:

> Open up your /etc/fstab file in an editor of your liking (as sudo).
>
> Look for the line that describes the partition you are running Ubuntu
>   on. For example:
>
> UUID=f54ae48f-7525-4b18-92bf-dbe5b1fb9be6 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
>
> Add a barrier=0 option so it now looks like this:
>
> UUID=f54ae48f-7525-4b18-92bf-dbe5b1fb9be6 / ext4
>   barrier=0,errors=remount-ro 0 1

Comment: Thank you a lot! Also helps with Ubuntu 14 and Rails 4, Selenium+Capybara tests (no Rspec).

Comment: This doesn't explain the exact why but more info on ext4 barrier. With ext3, barrier is set to false, with ext4 it's set to true by default. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt

Comment: Thank you so much! Before I see this, it takes like an hour for me to run only 50 examples rspec. But after see this and follow your guide, I only need more than 20 minutes to run my 2,500 examples rspec.

Comment: 5 years later, seems to be working for me!  Thanks a lot!  However, I'll add that I had to reboot after editing the fstab file for it to actually speed up.  Not sure if this is common knowledge, but I didn't know.

Comment: This broke my fstab file and I spent 40 minutes recovering from this debacle.  Ubuntu 16.04.