# Rspec very slow on Ubuntu but fast on Mac

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, phantomjs, rspec2

I am using:

> Rails 3.2.13
>
> Ruby 1.9.3-p448
>
> rvm 1.22.17 (master)
>
> phantomjs 1.9.2 (binary downloaded from site)
>
> Ubuntu 13.04 (64 bit)
>
> Rspec 2.12.2
>
> rspec-rails 2.12.0
>
> poltergeist 1.3.0
>
> capybara 2.1.0
>
> sqlite3 1.3.5

Asus laptop with these specs:

> Memory: 7.7 GiB
>
> Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz × 4
>
> Graphics (onboard): Intel® Sandybridge Mobile
>
> Regular HDD (not SSD)

I use a mid-2011 iMac at work, and the rspec test suite runs on that in about 5 minutes. It's slow, but bearable.

I use Ubuntu at home, and don't have a Mac. I wanted to do some work on my Ubuntu machine. The test suite takes about 30 minutes! (The first time it took an HOUR!)

I think this is capyabara/phantomjs's fault, but I am not sure. Those tests just seem the slowest. The other tests also seem slow, but the headless js ones seem very slow.

I have tried a number of things:

1. Updated rspec-rails, capybara, and poltergiest gems (although this would not be a long term solution anyway, because I would need to keep in line with works gemfile)
2. Updated RVM
3. Save changing to Ruby 2, this is the latest version (and again, I want to keep as close to works specs as possible)
4. Advice [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583669/rspec-incredibly-slow-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04) to add barrier=0 to fstab
5. Running with zeus gem (although this seems to then not report anything to simplecov to let me see coverage)
6. Searched fruitlessly through phantomjs, capybara, rspec, and poltergeist issue trackers for similar issues.

So far, my best times are around the 30 minute mark. Just running my feature tests takes around 30 minutes (so I am fairly certain these are the slow ones).

I've seen some rather daunting guides online for changing the fstab more for faster ext4 performance at the expense of stability. Maybe I just have a terrible laptop? I don't know, thought the specs were decent enough.

I am close to just buying a Mac (and going into debt) to get some work done. Is there anything else I can do, or are there any other problems/ideas I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Zeus gem to speed things up? Here is an awesome screen cast(free) by Ryan Bates showing how Zeus can speed things up http://railscasts.com/episodes/412-fast-rails-commands

Also Check out following screen casts:

If above screen cast doesn't solves your problem then try "Fast Tests" screen cast in which Ryan shows you how to speed up testing using Zeus and various other tools.
[Requires Pro subscription]http://railscasts.com/episodes/413-fast-tests

http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I have tried with Zeus (and it does indeed speed up nearly everything by preloading rails beforehand). However, it's not helping with my tests, and also seems to ruin simplecov reporting :( Either there is an underlying issue with Ubuntu, or my laptop is just not able to work as well as the Mac. It seems like it wouldn't be such a drastic difference in speed. I am watching the screencasts now but I don't think they will solve this. Thanks though!

Comment: @d3vkit : Try 2nd screen cast("Fast Tests") and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: I will give it a shot, thanks. I somehow missed that you pointed to a different screencast than what I was watching (I was watching fast rails commands). Will try fast tests.

Comment: I also recommend checking barrier mount option for ext4 drives with Ubuntu. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583669/rspec-incredibly-slow-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04 and look into the barrier option via https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt first to see if it's for you.