# Why is RSpec so slow on windows?

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

Yes, taking the risk to get the whole Rails community over me...

... why is RSpec so slow on windows? And with slow I mean slow. 710 examples in 47 minutes. Minutes!

Compared with cucumber on the same PC, 183 scenario's, and some 1280 steps in 1.26 minutes

RSpec - models and controllers
Cucumber - all possible user interactions

I know that RSpec is slow, but I definitely would like to find out why on average 4 seconds is spent on every example. I already ran RSpec to show me the top-10 slowest, but it seems a "general" slowness, not anything in particular

I'm a "happy windows user" (yes this does exist!), except for RSpec...

Comment: This is the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627888/rails-on-windows-is-so-slow-rails-v-takes-4-seconds

Comment: Any reason why this doesn't show up in using cucumber? The dots fly over the screen...  Cucumber is using the same objects, fixtures, ...

Comment: "I know that RSpec is slow" - would you please provide some sources to back up this claim?

Comment: Could you amend your question to include the time it takes to run an empty spec file: `rspec empty_spec.rb` and then a spec file that only contains `require 'spec_helper'`? Please include both the RSpec-reported time and the [system-reported time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line)

Comment: Could you amend your question to include system information, Ruby versions, application dependencies (like databases)?

Comment: @Shepmaster: if you would like to find out where things are going wrong, I can still do this. For myself, I surrendered yesterday, moving to Ubuntu in VirtualBox. Since this morning, website up and running again. Testing reduced from 45 mins to 7 mins, without any modification. Frustrating.

Comment: And after following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583669/rspec-incredibly-slow-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04, it was further reduced to 2 mins. Pretty happy now...